# How to connect ms excel-2007 with mysql.

Tags: mysql, excel, excel-2007, export-to-excel, vba

How to connect excel-2007 with mysql. I am on windows 7, 64 bit. Using excel-2007 32 bit and mysql version 5.1 , 32 bit. Can Anyone help me how to import my mysql table data in excel file. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I am adding to @Anil Chahal answer:

After configuration as described by @Anil Chahal, following code can be used to fetch data from MySql into Excel.

```
Function runQuery()
Dim cn As Object
Dim rs As Object
Dim strSql As String
Dim strConnection As String

Set cn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")

'Set your DB particulars
strConnection = "Data Source=MySQLExcel;Driver={MySQL ODBC 5.5.25a Driver};Server=" & _
                "localhost" & ";Database=" & "your-db-name" & _
                ";Uid=" & "your-user-name" & ";Pwd=" & "your-password" & ";"

    cn.Open strConnection
'Set your MySql query, i used "Select" query
    strSql = "SELECT * from Table-Name;"

    Set rs = cn.Execute(strSql)

'In case of "Select query" set your range to show records
'In case of "insert/edit/delete query" exclude next two lines
    Worksheets("SearchResults").Range("a4:xfd1048576").ClearContents
    Range("b4").CopyFromRecordset rs

'close the connection
    rs.Close
    Set rs = Nothing
    cn.Close
    Set cn = Nothing
```

End Function

Comment: This has been tested with MS-Office 2010 and also works for later versions.

Answer (score 7):

To connect your excel-2007 (or any version) with your mysql you need ODBC driver. Please download correct ODBC driver from the authenticated link

http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/odbc/

Please ensure you download the correct .msi or zip file according to your computer bit architecture. You need to ensure your Mysql running on 32 bit or 64 bit. Please follow this link to check

[MySQL: check what version : 32 bit or 64 bit?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7045295/mysql-check-what-version-32-bit-or-64-bit)

Now after that please ensure your excel-2007 is 32 bit or 64 bit. For this open excel file and start the task manager and check your bit architecture under Processes option. [image]

In my case, i am using windows7 64 bit, excel is 32 bit, mysql is also 32 bit

So i downloaded Windows (x86, 32-bit), MSI Installer from this link

http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/odbc/

**Now very important step :
In order to use a 32 bit ODBC driver on a 64 bit Windows machine, it has to be configured using a 32 bit ODBC Administrator which is not visible through normal Windows menu options. Utilities for 32 bit operations are found in the C:\Windows\SysWOW64 directory. 
We need to add the SysWOW64 directory to the system path, as follows**

```
 1. Click on start menu, right Click on My Computer -> Properties -> Advanced system settings
 2. Choose Advanced Tab -> Environmental Variables -> System Variables 
 3. Select and edit the PATH variable. Prefix the PATH list with 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64;'!
```

[image]

As of now correct path is set for installed ODBC Driver, now we need to create DSN (Data Source Name) for linking between excel and mysql. 
Now Open Control Panel and click on the Administrative Tools menu item to begin the installation of a new data source. Select Data Source ODBC , This is where you add a new User Data Source. Click the Add button on the right of the dialog box.
Now after pressing add button if you are able to see your Installed Driver in New Create Data Source pop up like this [image]

then its good if you follow this link for linkage between excel and mysql.

http://blog.mclaughlinsoftware.com/microsoft-excel/accessing-to-mysql/

If you not able to find your installed driver and pop up window for New Create Data Source looks like this

[image]

Need not to panic if your installed driver not listed over there.
Access the ODBC administrator utility located at 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\odbcad32.exe'.

Search for odbcad32.exe in 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64' directory

[image]

Now double click on second option of search result "odbcad32"

[image]

Now click on add button and select MySQL ODBC 5.3 ANSI Driver, click finish

```
In pop up window enter your details e.g. Data Source Name = MySQLExcel
Description = MySQL Excel Connector/ODBC
Server = localhost
Username and password of mysql, and name of the database.
```

Click on Test if everything is ok then you got a confirmation "Connection Successful"[image]

After the test, you return to the first screen where you should see that you’ve added a MySQLExcel Data Source Name. Click the OK button to dismiss the affirmation of the test.

Now to set up data importing from mysql to excel, Open excel, click on the Data Ribbon. Click the From Other Sources button. In the drop down menu, click on the From Data Connection Wizard item, which launches the Data Connection Wizard.

Select Other/Advanced item from the list of data sources. Click the Next button to continue.

Choose the Microsoft OLE DB Provider for ODBC Drivers item from the list of OLE DB Provider(s). Click the Next button to continue.

Choose the Connection tab in the Data Link Properties dialog. Under item #1, choose the Data Source Name (DSN) from the drop down box (set in a previous statement). Under item #2, enter the user name and password for mysql. Under item #3, select database.[image]

Click on test connection to ensure everything is ok.

[image]

Then, click the OK button on the Data Link Properties dialog.

Select the table name and click on next button

[image]

Now click on finish button.
The Data Import Wizard is complete with the last step. Now, you must import the data into the existing worksheet or a new worksheet.

[image]

Now press ok button. your mysql data will be there in excel file. Final response looks like this.[image]

Answer (score 0):

I use DAO to connect between Excel (2007) and my database (typically MS Access).

To do this, you need to:

Add Microsoft DAO 3.6 Object Library to your VBAProject References (i.e. Tools ─► References).

code would look something like this:

```
Sub MySub() 
  Set Db = OpenDatabase("C:\MyDB.mdb") 
  Set rst = Db.OpenRecordset(" SELECT * FROM MyTable") 
  ' output 
  Sheets.Add 
  With ActiveSheet.Cells(2, 1) 
     rec_QTY = .CopyFromRecordset(rst) 
  End With 
  rst.Close 
  Db.Close 
End Sub
```

Or if you want to execute a specific command:

```
Sub MySub_single_command()
  Set Db = OpenDatabase("C:\MyDB.mdb")
  Db.Execute (" DELETE * FROM MyTable;")
  Db.Close
End Sub
```

cheers,
Mike