# Excel connection to MySQL run-time error -2147467259 (80004005)

Tags: mysql, excel, vba

I have this code here:

```
Sub Example()
    Dim Conn As New Connection

    Conn.ConnectionString = "Server=localhost;Port=3306;Database=testing;Uid=root;Pwd=test;"
    Conn.Open

    Dim rs As New Recordset
    Dim sql As String
    sql = "Select productcode from labels"   'put spec of desired table here
    rs.Open sql, Conn
    If Not rs.EOF Then
        Range("a1").CopyFromRecordset rs
    End If
    rs.Close
    Set rs = Nothing
    Conn.Close
    Set Conn = Nothing
End Sub
```

And get this error code:

```
run-time error -2147467259 (80004005)
```

How can I fix this? What I am trying to do is:

Export data from MYSQL to excel without using the add-in.

Comment: Welcome to SO. What is the full error message? Does it stop at `Conn.Open` line? Also could you please confirm that Database, Uid and Pwd valid?

Comment: Hi @JustynaMK it does not highlight anything unfortunately

Comment: Thanks for an update - I don't have MySQL on my side, but hopefully the answer I posted will lead you in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

I needed to update `ConnectionString` with the valid Server, Database, User ID and password, as I'm using SQL server on my side.

Now, if I pause your code at `sql = "Select productcode from labels"` line and run it, the code will fail, highlight `ConnectionString` line and return the following error message:

[image]

Following the error message, I needed to specify the default driver to make the code run properly. In my case it looked like this:

`Conn.ConnectionString = "Driver={SQL Server};Server=...`

As you are using MySQL, I suggest trying one of the following (check ODBC version):

`Driver={MySQL ODBC 5.2 UNICODE Driver};`

`Driver={MySQL ODBC 5.2 ANSI Driver};`

Comment: Thanks for checking. Can you stop the macro at the same line as I did (`sql = "Select ...`) and paste the screenshot of an error message? What happens when you press the `Debug` button (i.e. which line is highlighted)?

Comment: Hi,  Now it says [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Data source name not found no default driver specified

Comment: I have managed to overcome the first error, now thats the new one ^

Comment: In that case, check out this [topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8240050/connecting-to-mysql-causes-error-data-source-name-not-found-and-no-default-driv) for MySQL and see if it provided a solution. From what you described it potentially presents an issue with 32 vs 64-bit versions.

Comment: just trying to find the righ tversion

Comment: how do I find which version I need?

Comment: Go to Registry Editor, `Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\ODBC\ODBCINST.INI\ODBC Drivers`, and check if you have `MySQL ODBC` installed in there; also take the note of the name and compare it to `Driver` parameter you set up in your VBA code. As for MySQL version, I don't have it installed but [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7045295/mysql-check-what-version-32-bit-or-64-bit) seems to be helpful.